# view-based NSTableView's views from XIB?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsviewcontroller

Is it possible to have a separate XIB file for the `NSTableCellView` of a view-based `NSTableView`? Maybe with the help of a `NSViewController`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it seems to be possible.

From Apple's documentation:

> In order to function, a programmatically implemented view-based table must implement the following:
>
> ...
>
> The - (NSView *)tableView:viewForTableColumn:row: method that is defined by the NSTableViewDelegate Protocol. This method both provides the table with the view to display as the cell for the specific column and row, as well as populates that cell with the appropriate data.

This way you can have an object of the class NSView (or any subclass) and give it back, after you properly filled it with data. Where you get this object from, is not of interest. As far as I know, it would be possible to do the following, for example:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Assume you have a XIB called View.xib
    [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"View" owner:self];
    
    // And you have an IBOutlet to your NSTableView (that's view based) called tView
    [tView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
     return 20;
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
   viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
                  row:(NSInteger)row {


    // Assume your class has an IBOutlet called contentOfTableView, 
    // your class is File's Owner of the View.xib and you connected the outlet.
    return contentOfTableView;

}
```

Hope it works. I just threw it together having a rough idea in mind. Good luck!

Comment: Thank You! So contentOfTableView is some NSView? How does the view know which NIB to load?

Comment: If you set your controller class to be the Files Owner within View.xib and then use: loadNibNamed you are loading the nib itself. By specifying self to be the owner (compare method of NSBundle) you tell Cocoa the placeholder shall be - yeah - replaced by your controller object. Within the View.xib you connected the IBOutlet contentOfTableView to files owner. And this is your controller now after your xib was loaded into memory. So you can use this outlet completely as though you declared it as a usual outlet within the same xib.